# Change html matching tags colors in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to edit vscode background color for matching open and close tags. Please don't recommend extensions for this because the default vscode color for matching tags overrides the extensions I tried to use.

[image]

I tried to change the colors by adding to Settings.JSON these lines of code

```
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": [
                    "entity.name.tag.html",
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "background": "#fff",
                }
            }
        ]
    },
```

But I get an error that says `Token background colors are not currently supported`.

If I try to change for example the `foreground` it works, so it's not an error in my code.

I've seen that color themes can change the background of matching tags, but I don't want to change my current color theme because it's the one that doesn't hurt my eyes too much when I try to read code.

Is there a way to change the background color of the matching tags?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76813932/836330 for related info.