# why my vscode cursor show a block around div

Tags: visual-studio-code

As soon as i go inside a DIV tag or any function, my vscode shows a blank box around those tags.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhhQ2.png)I have added an image as well. Can someone help me disable this? so i can see only my cursor and not the blank boxes.

I tried to find the Cursor Style in VSCode and nothing is fixing this.
Please let me know what option i need to enable/disable.

Comment: it shows the matching open/close tags

Comment: do you mean the boxes around the `<` and `>` characters? I do not have that. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

For the border boxes around the angle brackets, modify this setting:

```
Editor: Match Brackets     // set to 'never'
```

or to change its colors, use these `colorCustomiztions`:

```
"editorBracketMatch.border": "#ff0000",
"editorBracketMatch.background": "#00ff37",
```

---

For the text of the tag (your `div`) see this:

You will have to change 2 ThemeColors in your `settings.json` if you want to get rid of those colors.  There is no enable/disable setting for that feature of highlighting the matching html tag.  You can disable the setting `Editor: Linked Editing` but you may want that ability and you will still have to modify a ThemeColor.  In your `settings.json`:

```json
{
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    
    "editor.linkedEditingBackground": "#0000", // if you have Editor: Linked Editing enabled
    "editor.wordHighlightBackground": "#0000"  // do this even if linked editing is disabled
  }
}
```

The above sets both ThemeColors to **transparent**.

From [GH issue on coloring matching html tags](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/120817#issuecomment-815693060)